# Why is window.setTimeout(someFunc, 0) not the same as calling someFunc directly?

Tags: javascript, drop-down-menu

I am trying to implement a drop down menu using JS in my webpage. I know this is possible with CSS, but I still want to use JS to accomplish this.

So I searched around on Google and found this code:

```js
var timeout         = 500;
var closetimer      = 0;
var ddmenuitem      = 0;

// open hidden layer
function mopen(id)
{   
    // cancel close timer
    mcancelclosetime();

    // close old layer
    if(ddmenuitem) ddmenuitem.style.visibility = 'hidden';

    // get new layer and show it
    ddmenuitem = document.getElementById(id);
    ddmenuitem.style.visibility = 'visible';

}
// close showed layer
function mclose()
{
    if(ddmenuitem) ddmenuitem.style.visibility = 'hidden';
}

function mclosetime()
{
    closetimer = window.setTimeout(mclose, timeout);
}

// cancel close timer
function mcancelclosetime()
{
    if(closetimer)
    {
        window.clearTimeout(closetimer);
        closetimer = null;
    }
}

// close layer when click-out
document.onclick = mclose;
```

```css
#sddm
{   margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    z-index: 30}

#sddm li
{   margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    list-style: none;
    float: left;
    font: bold 11px arial}

#sddm li a
{   display: block;
    margin: 0 1px 0 0;
    padding: 4px 10px;
    width: 60px;
    background: #5970B2;
    color: #FFF;
    text-align: center;
    text-decoration: none}

#sddm li a:hover
{   background: #49A3FF}

#sddm div
{   position: absolute;
    visibility: hidden;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    background: #EAEBD8;
    border: 1px solid #5970B2}

    #sddm div a
    {   position: relative;
        display: block;
        margin: 0;
        padding: 5px 10px;
        width: auto;
        white-space: nowrap;
        text-align: left;
        text-decoration: none;
        background: #EAEBD8;
        color: #2875DE;
        font: 11px arial}

    #sddm div a:hover
    {   background: #49A3FF;
        color: #FFF}
```

```html
<ul id="sddm">
    <li><a href="#" onmouseover="mopen('m1')" onmouseout="mclosetime()">Home</a>
        <div id="m1" onmouseover="mcancelclosetime()" onmouseout="mclosetime()">
        <a href="#">HTML DropDown</a>
        <a href="#">DHTML DropDown menu</a>
        <a href="#">JavaScript DropDown</a>
        <a href="#">DropDown Menu</a>
        <a href="#">CSS DropDown</a>
        </div>
    </li>
    <li><a href="#" onmouseover="mopen('m2')" onmouseout="mclosetime()">Download</a>
        <div id="m2" onmouseover="mcancelclosetime()" onmouseout="mclosetime()">
        <a href="#">ASP Dropdown</a>
        <a href="#">Pulldown menu</a>
        <a href="#">AJAX dropdown</a>
        <a href="#">DIV dropdown</a>
        </div>
    </li>
    <li><a href="#" onmouseover="mopen('m3')" onmouseout="mclosetime()">Order</a>
        <div id="m3" onmouseover="mcancelclosetime()" onmouseout="mclosetime()">
        <a href="#">Visa Credit Card</a>
        <a href="#">Paypal</a>
        </div>
    </li>
    <li><a href="#" onmouseover="mopen('m4')" onmouseout="mclosetime()">Help</a>
        <div id="m4" onmouseover="mcancelclosetime()" onmouseout="mclosetime()">
        <a href="#">Download Help File</a>
        <a href="#">Read online</a>
        </div>
    </li>
    <li><a href="#" onmouseover="mopen('m5')" onmouseout="mclosetime()">Contact</a>
        <div id="m5" onmouseover="mcancelclosetime()" onmouseout="mclosetime()">
        <a href="#">E-mail</a>
        <a href="#">Submit Request Form</a>
        <a href="#">Call Center</a>
        </div>
    </li>
</ul>
<div style="clear:both"></div>

<div style="clear:both"></div>
```

I edited the JS a bit because I want the dropdown to disappear immediately after the mouse pointer moves out of dropdown. So I changed it to this:

```
function mclosetime()
{
    closetimer = window.setTimeout(mclose, 0);
}
```

and removed the `timeout` variable. Everything still works. Then I realized that `mclosetime` basically calls `mclose` with a delay of 0. I thought `mclosetime` is a function that does not do much and can be removed. So I removed it and changed the `li` elements to directly call `mclose`:

```
    <li><a href="#" onmouseover="mopen('m1')" onmouseout="mclose()">Home</a>
        <div id="m1" onmouseover="mcancelclosetime()" onmouseout="mclose()">
        <a href="#">HTML DropDown</a>
        <a href="#">DHTML DropDown menu</a>
        <a href="#">JavaScript DropDown</a>
        <a href="#">DropDown Menu</a>
        <a href="#">CSS DropDown</a>
        </div>
    </li>
```

Then the dropdown does not work anymore! The dropdown disappears as soon as I move the mouse pointer to the dropdown menu. I thought this is caused by `closetimer` being 0, so I changed `mclose` to this:

```
function mclose()
{
    closetimer = 1;
    if(ddmenuitem) ddmenuitem.style.visibility = 'hidden';
}
```

Still the same thing happens.

I am really confused. Doesn't `window.setTimeout` just call the function if the timeout is 0? If it doesn't do anythng more than that, calling `mclose` here should work!

Comment: Technically, `setTimeout(func,delay)` means to call `func` in _no less than_ `delay` msecs, not _exactly after_ `delay` msecs.

Comment: @Passerby Why would that make a difference? Also, can you give me the link to the documentation? I read the page about `setTimeout` on W3Schools and it does not seem to mention this.

Comment: Please read [this MDN document](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WindowOrWorkerGlobalScope/setTimeout), especially the "Notes" part.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`setTimeout(myFun, 0)` cannot gurantee that `myFun` will get called straight away.

Under the hook, when you do `window.setTimeout(myFun, 0)`, the browser just puts the function `myFun` to the browser event queue. And the browser will execute it immediately only if there is nothing else in the queue. So is there is something existing in the queue, it will be executed earlier than your `myFun`.

Comment: I see now! It is this delay that causes `mclose` to be called a little later. During this delay, my mouse moves into the dropdown menu and the timeout is canceled.

Answer (score 0):

`setTimout` works asynchronously. That means, it queues `mclose` to run once the current call stack is finished executing. If you call `mclose` directly, it executes in current call stack in sequence (synchronously) but `setTimout` executes it immediately in the next call stack.

Answer (score 0):

There is no issue with your **setTimeout** function. The problem lies with JavaScript's `mouse-out` event, it gets applied to the nested child elements as well. As soon as you move the mouse over to the child DIV, the mouse out event of the parent is fired. **JQuery** provides a simple solution to this problem by using its `mouseleave` event which does exactly what you want.

https://api.jquery.com/mouseleave/